# Limit of $e^{-\bar{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Does limit $e^{-\bar{z}}$ when z goes to zero is 0.

I understand that firstly we rewrite $e^{-\bar{z}}=e^{-(x-iy)}=e^(iy-x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is $1$.

$z \to \overline {z}$ is continuous, so $\overline {z} \to 0$ as $ z \to 0$. Since exponential is continuous we see that the given limit is $e^{0}=1$.